# Download Email from Specific Outlook Folder and Save

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm getting a run-time error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" at the line below

```
 Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

- Go to the folder titled Spreadsheets within my Outlook - where there will be 2-3 emails. May be read, may be unread - So I don't want to restrict to unread like some of the code I've seen on here.
- Download all of the attachments from these emails to a folder on my desktop
- Then delete all of the emails that are located within that Spreadsheets Outlook folder (I have yet to include this part in the code)

I've tried modifying the code a bunch. But I've been unable to get it to work. I guess I just have had some trouble understanding what each part is doing.

```
Sub GetAttachments()

Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
Dim oOlItm As Object, SubFolder As Object, oOlAtch As Object
Dim NewFileName As String
Const AttachmentPath As String = "\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\Testing Email Download"

NewFileName = AttachmentPath & "Work?"

Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oOlns = oOlAp.getnamespace("MAPI")
Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = oOlInb.Folders("Test")
If SubFolder.oOlItm.Count > 0 Then
For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.attachments
oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & oOlAtch.FileName
Exit For
Next
Else: End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Is this error solved somehow?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

You need to change the for each loop as follows:

```
'~~> Store the relevant info in the variables
For Each oOlItm In SpecFolder.Items
    eSender = oOlItm.SenderEmailAddress
    dtRecvd = oOlItm.ReceivedTime
    dtSent = oOlItm.CreationTime
    sSubj = oOlItm.Subject
    sMsg = oOlItm.Body
    For Each att in oOlItm.Attachments
        att.SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & att.FileName
    Next
    oOlItm.Delete()
    Exit For
Next
```

You are interested in the [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359(v=office.15).aspx) method which saves the attachment to the specified path.

The [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343(v=office.15).aspx) method removes the item from the folder that contains the item.

Comment: I was getting an error while setting the workbook. Please see the new edit.

Comment: What error are you talking about? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I just finished the edit right now. It's the runtime error.

Comment: Everywhere I've been reading says this is a necessary line of code. But according to my excel it's invalid.

Comment: In the Editor try setting a reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library. Tools menu | References